# Problem with MMD warping animation

Tags: animation

When using mmd files the animation ends up warped. What could be done to fix this error?

[image: frame 1]
Frame 1: model looks right
[image: warped animation]

All other frames: model looks warped

Comment: Looks as though your face indexes are messed up. How do you create the original model? If it is an OBJ try using the "Keep Vert Order" option. Then use mesh cache modifier on the imported object to apply the MDD file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep Vert Order needs to be on when using mmd in Blender to avoid warped geometry.

Workflow:

1. File >> Import >> .obj, on right options, turn on Keep Vert Order
   [image: vert order]
2. Select imported object
3. File >> Import .mmd

Comment: It should have been @beiller posting the answer, since you didn't know it, and he told you how...

Comment: @someonewithpc we can't force beiller to write an answer, at least the op took the time to do this.

Comment: Hehe go ahead and accept. I don't know how to post screen shots yet so cred!